# How to write python web service server WSDL?

Tags: python, web-services, python-3.x

All the stuff I am seeing points me towards writing clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the popular approach is to hand-write WSDL first (typically with an XML-oriented editor, of course, such as [oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)), then generate a Python server skeleton from it with [wsdl2py](http://www.opensourcetutorials.com/tutorials/Server-Side-Coding/Python/python-soap-libraries-4/page2.html).  Unfortunately I have no first-hand experience with this so I'm not sure if it works as well as it's advertised to.